# JS Facebook API Request seems to break sessions

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, firefox-addon, facebook-apps

I have a firefox extension that requests different APIs via XMLHttpRequest. However, the facebook like/share/comment count request leads to a logout in some online shops and some websites.

For example, GMX webmail has to restore the session after every click. Some online-shops seems to loose the session completeley so that there is an empty basket.

The problem only occurs with the facebook request enabled.

**Request URL**

```
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20click_count,%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22www.heise.de%22&format=JSON
```

**Javascript Code for the Request**

```
        var querystring = facebookURL + encodedUrl + facebookURLParams; // looks like the above
        var mFacebookRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        mFacebookRequest.onload = parseFacebookResponse;
        mFacebookRequest.open( "GET", querystring );
// already tried without user-agent
        mFacebookRequest.setRequestHeader( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP 5.1)" );
```

**parseFacebookResponse function**

```
         function parseFacebookResponse() {
                var fbcount = "-";
                var share_count = 0;
                var like_count = 0;
                var comment_count = 0;

                var aDoc = mFacebookRequest.responseText;
                if( aDoc == null || aDoc == -1 || aDoc.length == 0 )
                {

                } else {

                    var jsonDoc = JSON.parse( aDoc );
                    var temp = jsonDoc[0];

                    share_count     = parseInt(temp['share_count']);
                    like_count      = parseInt(temp['like_count']);
                    comment_count   = parseInt(temp['comment_count']);



                }
```

**The code is working perfectly and the numbers are displayed. But it keeps me logging out. Any idea?!**

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You can track the request with HttpFox, check if send any unexpected request, so make the cookies of eshop changed?

Answer (score 1):

you are making a cross domain XML HTTP request. This coupled with the possibility that the GMX website is setting an immediately expiring session cookie -- your session is killed. This is just a hypothesis.

Comment: Sounds like "could be the problem" but i am doing like ten XMLHTTPRequests and this is the only one with that problem..